# How to append child in the div parent node?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I need to append childnodes to their parent nodes, but parent node should be `div`.

I need to check, if parent node is not `div` then, check parent's parent node until I get div node. How to do it?

**XML file**

```
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="boxed-text">box text1</div>
      <li>
        <div class="boxed-text">box text2</div>
        <p>para</p>
      </li>
      <div class="boxed-text">box text3</div>
      <p>para</p>
    </div>
```

**Expected output(should append to the div parent node)**

```
    <div class="parent">
      <li>
        <p>para</p>
      </li>     
      <p>para</p>
      <div class="boxed-text">box text1</div>
      <div class="boxed-text">box text2</div>
      <div class="boxed-text">box text3</div>
    </div>
```

But I have got an output like below:(i.e. parent node of boxed-text 2 is `li`tag so, it get appended there instead of div parent node. How to get only div parent node to append child  nodes? )

```
    <div class="parent">
      <li>
        <p>para</p>
        <div class="boxed-text">box text2</div>
      </li>     
      <p>para</p>
      <div class="boxed-text">box text1</div>
      <div class="boxed-text">box text3</div>
    </div>
```

**my code:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load("new_test.xml", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$div = $xp->query("//div[@class='boxed-text']");
foreach($div as $divv) {
    $divv->parentNode->appendChild($divv);
    }
$r = $dom->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You append the node to their parent node, but this will just move them to the last position inside the parent - it will not change the parent.

Xpath has a concept of axes. The default axis is `child` - the children of the current context. But here a several others including `ancestor` which represents the path back to the document root.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->load("new_test.xml", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");

$divs = $xp->evaluate("//div[@class='boxed-text']");
foreach($divs as $div) {
  $ancestor = $xp->evaluate('ancestor::div[1]', $div)->item(0);
  if ($ancestor) {
    $ancestor->appendChild($div);
  }
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div class="parent">
  <li>
    <p>para</p>
  </li>
  <p>para</p>
  <div class="boxed-text">box text1</div>
  <div class="boxed-text">box text2</div>
  <div class="boxed-text">box text3</div>
</div>
```

Another way would be to traverse the parent div elements and get the boxed-text descendants for each of them:

```
$parents = $xp->evaluate("//div[.//div[@class='boxed-text']]");
foreach ($parents as $parent) {
  foreach ($xp->evaluate(".//div[@class='boxed-text']", $parent) as $text) {
    $parent->appendChild($text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I tried second way,It works.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not tested but I would use the XPath to get the parent node explicitly rather than using the parentNode method you are currently and remove the div elements from the dom in the first loop and then add them back at the end

```
$tmp=array();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( "new_test.xml", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );

$xp = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");

/* Find the parent based on it's class */
$parent=$xp->query("//div[class='parent']")->item(0);

/* Find the nodes of interest and remove - store in temp array */
$col = $xp->query("//div[@class='boxed-text']");
foreach( $col as $node ) $tmp[]=$parent->removeChild( $node );

/* Add the nodes back at the end */
foreach( $tmp as $node ) $parent->appendChild( $node );

$r = $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: Actually, `div class="parent"` is just an example, class would be anything that is not pre-defined.